# How to retrieve the node values from a constparty object?

Tags: r

I was trying to find an optimal dichotomized threshold for a continuous variable fitted to a survival model and I was using partykit::ctree() for this purpose:

```
> library(survival)
> library(partykit)
Loading required package: grid
> data("GBSG2", package = "TH.data")


> stree <- ctree(Surv(time, cens) ~ tsize, data = GBSG2)
> stree$node
[1] root
|   [2] V2 <= 19 *
|   [3] V2 > 19
|   |   [4] V2 <= 61 *
|   |   [5] V2 > 61 *
```

My question is how to retrieve the fitted thresholds (e.g. 19 and 61 in the above example).

```
> class(stree)
[1] "constparty" "party"
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out but may be not the best way though.

`stree$node$split$breaks`

or

`stree@tree$psplit$splitpoint`